# How does the typeof method works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, casting, typeof

```
if(typeof(variable) === "boolean"){
  // variable is a boolean
}
```

**Which one of the two code samples below is equivalent to the one above ?**

Sample 1

```
if(variable === true || variable === false){
  // variable is a boolean
}
```

Sample 2

```
if(variable == true || variable == false){
  // variable is a boolean
}
```

Comment: Clearly not the second, because `1 == true`, but is not a boolean

Comment: If that was your question, why not just try `typeof(1) == 'boolean'` in the console, rather than asking a human?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case is equivalent. The `===` performs the same operation as the `==`, except that it does not perform any **type conversions**. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1928852) for more details.

So,

```
if ( variable === true || variable === false) {
    ...
}
```

Will evaluate to true only when `variable` is a boolean variable.

---

As for the inner workings of `typeof`, you can read [this](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/) and, of course, it's [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). Keep in mind that `typeof` is a language operator, much like `===`, `==`, or `&`. To know exactly how it is implemented and how it knows the variable types, you need to check the code for it.

I never looked at a JavaScript Engine source code, so I don't know where you could look.